# How to keep PyQt5 UI responsive while waiting for serial feedback?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyserial

I'm developing a simple software where serial would be feeding back information and update on UI.

This software will be running in Raspbian Jessie, Python 3.4, PyQt5 and Pyserial.
This UI is drawn via Qt Designer and converted via pyuic.
The purpose of this software is to monitor 4 step motors that attached to my Pi, via MCU chip, and the serial information is from this MCU. I am not using Pi's GPIO as they has their other usage.

I wanted to get the text displayed on screen once the serial buffer is filled with information, for now.

I had tried the following code, but it's not good enough as I have to depend on timer to check on serial read. Is there another more efficient way to get the texts on screen once the serial port had received information?

```
import sys, datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
#import UI drawn from QtDesigner
from QFrame.Main_btn6 import Ui_MainWindow
import serial


def setupserial(object):    
    com = serial.Serial(port        = "/dev/ttyUSB0",
                        baudrate    = 115200,
                        parity      = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                        stopbits    = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                        bytesize    = serial.EIGHTBITS,                                  
                        timeout     = 3) #ms   
    return (com)


class Form_Operation(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.timer      = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.ui         = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.serialcom  = setupserial()
        self.timer.setInterval(10)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hidden)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)        
        self.initUI()    

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.MainDisplay.setText("Output from Serial comn.")

        Exit = self.ui.Btn_Exit
        Exit.clicked.connect(self.Exit_buttonClicked)

        Clear = self.ui.Btn_Clear
        Clear.clicked.connect(self.Clear_buttonClicked)

    def hidden(self):  
        """
        Get texts from serial
        """
        self.comread = self.com.readline().decode()        
        self.ui.MainDisplay.setText(self.comread)

    def Exit_buttonClicked(self):
        sys.exit()

    def Clear_buttonClicked(self):
        """ 
        Click to clear 
        """
        self.ui.MainDisplay.setText("")            

    def close(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.destroy() 

    def show(self):
        self.timer.start()
        self.showFullScreen() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    start = Form_Operation()
    start.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you may need to use Threading to start serial port and Queue to store the serial data. Refer


[RealTime Data Plotter](https://github.com/sunilthorat09/SerialPort-RealTime-Data-Plotter). This is quite similar to what you are doing.

Comment: Hi @SunilT, I'll try the link you provided. Thanks a lot mate!